# How Can I Get the Camel Content Enricher to Process an Exchange from a REST Call?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm building a sample implementation that routes orders to an order management system. Inbound to the route is an exchange with two identifiers, one for the customer ID and one for the catalog item ID. I then transform the body the inbound exchange to my Order domain object. My goal is then to call the content enricher pattern, once to aggregate data from the customer and one to aggregate data from the catalog item.

My route is:

```java
   @Override
   public void configure() {
      // Start by building an instance of RestConfigurationDefinition. Need to
      // specify the component we are going to use for enabling REST endpoints,
      // specifically CamelServlet in this case. Set the binding mode to JSON.
      restConfiguration().
            // Leverage the CamelServlet component for the REST DSL
            component("servlet").
            // Bind using JSON
            bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).
            // I like pretty things...
            dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true").
            // This is the context path to be used for Swagger API documentation
            apiContextPath("api-doc").
            // Properties for Swagger
            // Title of the API
      apiProperty("api.title", "Order Management API").
            // Version of the API
            apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0").
            // CORS (resource sharing) enablement
            apiProperty("cors", "true").
            // Use localhost for calls
            apiProperty("host", "localhost:8083").
            // Set base path
            apiProperty("base.path", "nvisia-order-router-camel-service/api");

      // Definition of the post order endpoint
      rest("/orderRouter").
            // This is a POST method call for routing an order using the
            // order form
      post().
            // Description of what the method does
            description("Routes a new order to the order management service").
            // Define the type used for input
            type(OrderForm.class).
            // Define the type used for output, in this case the order
            outType(String.class).
            // Next, define where the message is routed to, first transformation
            to("bean:orderRouterService?method=transformOrderFormToOrder(${body})")
            .to("direct:enrichOrder");

      // Definition of the enrich order endpoint
      from("direct:enrichOrder").
            // Use the Content Enricher EIP to aggregate customer info in the
            // order.
      enrich(
            "http4://localhost:8081/nvisia-customer-camel-service/api/customer/${body.customerId}",
            new AggregationStrategy() {
               @Override
               public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                  Order originalBody = (Order) oldExchange.getIn().getBody();
                  Customer resourceResponse = (Customer) newExchange.getIn().getBody();
                  originalBody.setCustomer(resourceResponse);
                  if (oldExchange.getPattern().isOutCapable()) {
                     oldExchange.getOut().setBody(originalBody);
                  } else {
                     oldExchange.getIn().setBody(originalBody);
                  }
                  return oldExchange;
               }
            }).
            // Use the Content Enricher EIP to aggregate catalog info in the
            // order.
      enrich(
            "http4://localhost:8080/nvisia-catalog-camel-service/api/customer/${body.catalogItemId}",
            new AggregationStrategy() {
               @Override
               public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                  Order originalBody = (Order) oldExchange.getIn().getBody();
                  CatalogItem resourceResponse = (CatalogItem) newExchange.getIn()
                        .getBody();
                  originalBody.setCatalogItem(resourceResponse);
                  if (oldExchange.getPattern().isOutCapable()) {
                     oldExchange.getOut().setBody(originalBody);
                  } else {
                     oldExchange.getIn().setBody(originalBody);
                  }
                  return oldExchange;
               }
            }).to("direct:sendOrder");

      // Definition of the send order endpoint
      from("direct:sendOrder").
            // Need to define the content type on the header
            setHeader(org.apache.camel.Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,
                  constant("application/json"))
            .
            // Be safe and define this as a post
            setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,
                  constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
            .
            // Finally, send the order to be managed and get back the order ID
            to("http4://localhost:8082/nvisia-order-management-camel-service/api/order");
   }
```

The exception I get is:

```
org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: OrderForm [customerId=1, catalogItemId=1] of type: com.nvisia.examples.camel.orderrouter.OrderForm on: Message[]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: com.nvisia.examples.camel.orderrouter.OrderForm to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value OrderForm [customerId=1, catalogItemId=1]. Exchange[ID-nvisia-mhoffman-50981-1463522552963-0-8]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: com.nvisia.examples.camel.orderrouter.OrderForm to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value OrderForm [customerId=1, catalogItemId=1]]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.createRequestEntity(HttpProducer.java:523)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.createMethod(HttpProducer.java:422)
    at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Enricher.process(Enricher.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:143)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.nvisia.examples.camel.orderrouter.OrderForm to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value OrderForm [customerId=1, catalogItemId=1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:105)
    ... 79 more
```

Note I am using the latest camel, 2.17.1. My question is, if I am getting an exchange where the body is in JSON format, how do I make the two content enricher calls to get my Order bean populated? As I don't need to send an input stream to either content enricher call, I considered having a processor before each exchange, but I think it will get challenging with the second aggregation to maintain the information from the first aggregation. If this is not a recommended way to use the content enricher, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by moving away from using the content enricher and instead just using multicast with two direct endpoints. I also needed to explicitly unmarshal and marshal, which was causing some additional issues as well. Here is the finalized route I used in case it is useful to anyone else.

```
  // Definition of the post order endpoint
  rest("/orderRouter")
        // This is a POST method call for routing an order using the order
        // form
        .post()
        // Description of what the method does
        .description("Routes a new order to the order management service")
        // Define the type used for input
        .type(OrderForm.class)
        // Define the type used for output, in this case the order
        .outType(OrderNumber.class)
        // Now, process the order
        .to("direct:processOrder");

  // This is the route that processes the order sent. First, we need to take
  // the data from the order form passed, put it in the header and empty out
  // the body of our incoming exchange.
  from("direct:processOrder")
        // Set header for customer ID
        .setHeader("customerId", simple("${body.customerId}"))
        // Set header for catalog item ID
        .setHeader("catalogItemId", simple("${body.catalogItemId}"))
        // Empty the body
        .setBody(constant(""))
        // Now, aggregate the data to an order type
        .end()
        // Use multicasting to call the customer and catalog item services
        // in parallel. Then, use a strategy that groups the exchanges
        // returned from the service calls into a single list for
        // processing.
        .multicast(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
        // Use parallel processing
        .parallelProcessing()
        // Send to two direct components to get the data
        .to("direct:getCustomerData", "direct:getCatalogItemData")
        // End the multicast call
        .end()
        // Now process the exchange
        .process(new Processor() {
           @Override
           public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
              List<Exchange> exchanges = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
              Order order = new Order();
              for (Exchange exchangeToProcess : exchanges) {
                 if (exchangeToProcess.getIn().getBody() instanceof Customer) {
                    order.setCustomer(
                          exchangeToProcess.getIn().getBody(Customer.class));
                 } else if (exchangeToProcess.getIn()
                       .getBody() instanceof CatalogItem) {
                    order.setCatalogItem(
                          exchangeToProcess.getIn().getBody(CatalogItem.class));
                 } else {
                    // Ignore it for now.
                 }
              }
              order.setOrderDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
              exchange.getIn().setBody(order);
           }
        })
        // End this processor definition
        .end()
        // Need to marshal the body to JSON
        .marshal()
        // Need to use JSON for marshalling
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        // Then convert it to a string
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        // We can now send the order to order management. Need to define the
        // content type on the header
        .setHeader(org.apache.camel.Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,
              constant("application/json"))
        // Be safe and define this as a post
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,
              constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
        // Set the HTTP uri to be used.
        .setHeader("CamelHttpUri", simple(
              "http://localhost:8082/nvisia-order-management-camel-service/api/order"))
        // Finally, send the order to be managed and get back the order ID
        .to("http4://localhost:8082/nvisia-order-management-camel-service/api/order")
        // Next, convert the input stream returned to a string
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        // Finally, unmarshal the string to an object
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, OrderNumber.class);

  // Retrieves the customer data from the REST service for customer.
  from("direct:getCustomerData")
        // Set the http method as GET
        .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("GET"))
        // Set the HTTP uri to be used.
        .setHeader("CamelHttpUri", simple(
              "http://localhost:8081/nvisia-customer-camel-service/api/customer/${header.customerId}"))
        // Define the endpoint; though, url will be ignored in favor of
        // header
        .to("http4://localhost:8081/nvisia-customer-camel-service/api/customer/${header.customerId}")
        // Next, convert the input stream returned to a string
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        // Finally, unmarshal the string to an object
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Customer.class);

  // Retrieves the catalog item data from the REST service for catalog
  // items.
  from("direct:getCatalogItemData")
        // Set the http method as GET
        .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("GET"))
        // Set the HTTP uri to be used.
        .setHeader("CamelHttpUri", simple(
              "http://localhost:8080/nvisia-catalog-camel-service/api/catalogItem/${header.catalogItemId}"))
        // Define the endpoint; though, url will be ignored in favor of
        // header
        .to("http4://localhost:8080/nvisia-catalog-camel-service/api/catalogItem/${header.catalogItemId}")
        // Next, convert the input stream returned to a string
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        // Finally, unmarshal the string to an object
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CatalogItem.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The option using enrich is like this [Integration Pattern](http://redhatgov.io/workshops/strangling_the_monolith/lab3/)

Don't use `http4` directly in `enrich`

```
<enrich strategyRef="myAgregator">
  <simple>http4://foo-url/</simple> <!-- InvalidPayloadException -->
</enrich>
```

So, use indirectly with `direct` uri:

```
<camel:route id="consume-service1">
  <from uri="direct:consume-service1" />
  <camel:removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*" />
  <to uri="http4://order-service/" />
  <unmarshal ref="orderJson" />
  <enrich strategyRef="myAgregator">
    <simple>direct:consume-service2</simple>
  </enrich>
  <marshal ref="myJson" />
</camel:route>

<camel:route id="consume-service2">
  <from uri="direct:consume-service2" />
  <camel:setBody><constant></constant></camel:setBody>
  <camel:removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*" />
  <to uri="http4://catalog-service" />
  <unmarshal ref="catalogJson" />
</camel:route>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this is a way simpler and better solution.